# Replace Characters in a Range in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, parsing

I have a chunk of code that looks like this:
`HiClass *myNewClass;`

Now, what I'm doing is writing a method to roll through and delete the Hi, as well as everything after it, including the *, so that only `myNewClass;` is left. Now, I take out the "Hi" like so:

```
    textToConvert = inputField.stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("Hi", withString: "", 
options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

But within this *same* method, if possible, I would like to somehow delete everything leaving only `myNewClass;`, as stated above.

My first though on how to approach this is to use a range. Though still being new to Swift and trying to avoid Objective-C, **I'm unsure of how to remove all of the characters between the Hi and the *, leaving only**`myClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method

```
var testStr = "HiClass *myNewClass"
let array   = testStr.componentsSeparatedByString("*")
testStr = String(array.last)
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, it only gave me the end values of the string.

Comment: don't you want to remove  all of the characters between the Hi and the * ? there other method can do this:        var str = "HiClass *myNewClass"
        let range = str.rangeOfString("*")
        str.removeRange(Range(start: str.startIndex, end: (range?.endIndex)!))

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf with Swift 2.0 to find the index, and just take a substring to the end of it like this:

```
var str = "HiClass *myNewClass"

if let idx = str.characters.indexOf("*") {
    var s = str.substringFromIndex(advance(idx, 1))
}
```

Comment: I don't believe .characters is a property of String, I'm getting an error there